# My delay on adding a button is not working in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, settimeout, sprite

For class we have to make our own game, and I want to make it so that after starting a certain scene, it waits 5 seconds to play a sprite. This works. But after it has played once, I want to make that sprite a button. I tried this by adding another file of the last frame of the spritesheet and adding a yellow outline (so that the player can see it's clickable). Just loading in the new sprite and making it a button works. But I don't want the button to be added from the beginning, only after 5 seconds when the original sprite has played once. I tried doing this using setTimeout, but now it doesn't load the sprite/button in at all. The sprite is a letter falling through the front door (letterbox?). So after the letter fell on the floor, I wan't to make it clickable so it moves on to the next scene. I am pretty new to JavaScript and I've never used the command setTimeout so I just want to know if I'm using it correctly, and if not, how to fix it. I tried it in two ways I found online:

1:

```
function deurKnop(){
    var deurButton = this.add.sprite(111, 289, 'klik_deur', 1).setScale(1);
    
    deurButton.setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });
    deurButton.on('pointerdown', () => { this.scene.start("gameScene2"); deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerover', () => { deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerout', () => { deurButton.setFrame(1); });
  };
setTimeout(deurKnop, 6000);
```

2:

```
setTimeout(function{
var deurButton = this.add.sprite(111, 289, 'klik_deur', 1).setScale(1);
    
    deurButton.setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });
    deurButton.on('pointerdown', () => { this.scene.start("gameScene2"); deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerover', () => { deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerout', () => { deurButton.setFrame(1); });
  }; ,6000);
```

But neither works. This is the code of the whole scene if that helps:

```
//scene 1, woonkamer
gameScene1.preload = function() {
    this.load.spritesheet('brievenbus', 'assets/sprites/brievenbus.PNG', { frameWidth: 280, frameHeight: 359 });// Nu werkt het!!!
    this.load.spritesheet('openhaard', 'assets/sprites/openhaard.png', { frameWidth: 381, frameHeight: 672 });
  this.load.spritesheet('klik_deur', 'assets/sprites/klikdeur.png', { frameWidth: 146, frameHeight: 192 });
  
    this.load.image('woonkamer', 'assets/backgrounds/woonkamer.JPG');
  this.load.image('woonkamer_deur', 'assets/backgrounds/woonkamer_deur.JPG');
};
gameScene1.create = function() {
    this.add.image(400, 279.5, 'woonkamer_deur');
  
  deur = this.physics.add.sprite(108, 288, 'brievenbus').setScale(0.49);
  vuur = this.physics.add.sprite(650, 320, 'openhaard').setScale(0.15);

    this.anims.create({
    key: 'go',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brievenbus', { frames: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14] }),
        frameRate: 23,
    delay: 5000,
        repeat: 0
    });
deur.anims.play('go', true);

  this.anims.create({
    key: 'Go',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('openhaard', { frames: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5] }),
        frameRate: 12,
        repeat: -1
    });
vuur.anims.play('Go', true);

  function deurKnop(){
    var deurButton = this.add.sprite(111, 289, 'klik_deur', 1).setScale(1);
    
    deurButton.setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });
    deurButton.on('pointerdown', () => { this.scene.start("gameScene2"); deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerover', () => { deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerout', () => { deurButton.setFrame(1); });
  };
setTimeout(deurKnop, 6000);
};
```

So basically the animation of 'brievenbus' happens after 5 seconds of starting this scene. I want the button to be shown and added after 6 seconds.

Comment: `this` does not refer to what you think it does. `setTimeout` is a callback function. It basically means "Count down from the number, and when done, call me back so I can continue doing other things in the meantime". So Javascript will continue its execution of other lines of code until the timer runs out and the `setTimeout` "calls" Javascript to come back and execute the function. `this` however typically refers to the caller. Your caller would be the `setTimeout` function. Obviously `setTimeout` has no idea what to do with `add.sprite`. So you need to fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### One way round the loss of meaning of `this` inside setTimeout is an arrow function

When you use the `function name_etc(){ actions_etc... }` way of defining a function, the `this` variable no longer refers to the parent `this`.

However, if you define the function with `()=>{ actions_etc... }`, the meaning of `this` is retained within the setTimeout function.

```
setTimeout(()=>{
var deurButton = this.add.sprite(111, 289, 'klik_deur', 1).setScale(1);
    
    deurButton.setInteractive({ cursor: 'pointer' });
    deurButton.on('pointerdown', () => { this.scene.start("gameScene2"); deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerover', () => { deurButton.setFrame(0); });
    deurButton.on('pointerout', () => { deurButton.setFrame(1); });
  }; ,6000);
```